# Word not being assigned to variable

Tags: python, string, input

im trying to find if given a word, my program will look to see if a capital letter is present and checks it. 

problem is, i cant even go through my program because i get an **error that says "name cAt" is not defined** (cAt) being what i inputed , not sure if this code will find an **uppercase in a given word**. 

is there a way to do this with regular expressions maybe something like,

`if : re.search("A,B,C etc")` ?

here's what i have,

```
g = input("enter a ")

h = [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRXTUVWXYZ]


for letters in g:
    if letters in h :
        print "upper"
```

Comment: `h = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRXTUVWXYZ"`

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.x., `input` evaluates its input as real Python code.  So, when you enter `cAt`, Python tries to find a variable by the same name.  And, since it can't, it blows up.

You need to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead, which returns input as a string object.

Also, you need to make `h` a string like this:

```
h = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRXTUVWXYZ"
```

---

However, you might want to look into [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and [`str.isupper`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) for this task:

```
>>> mystr = raw_input("enter a word: ")
enter a word: cAt
>>> mystr
'cAt'
>>> any(x.isupper() for x in mystr)
True
>>> mystr = raw_input("enter a word: ")
enter a word: cat
>>> mystr
'cat'
>>> any(x.isupper() for x in mystr)
False
>>>
```

Comment: or `from string import ascii_upper as h` :P

Comment: thanks for the tip. i changed it to what you said, and now if i type cAT, it prints "upper" 3 times. how do i stop this?

Comment: @ZachSantiago - The only thing I can think of that might cause your problem is if the print-statement is dedented so that it is outside the if-block.  But then you'd get a `SyntaxError` for having an empty code block.  So, I don't know what could be causing it.  Do you have any other code to post?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x, `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression.

You want to use `g=raw_input("enter a ")` so that `g` stores a string.

Python 3.x uses `input()` for both of the above.